# Why is my new LED fixture flashing when the switch is off?

Tags: led

I just purchased an LED 4ft light for my kitchen. I ran my wires up into the ceiling and tied them in with the existing light fixture which is not an LED fixture. When I turned the breaker back on, both lights were flashing on and off with the light switch off. What would cause this?

Comment: Welcome. There are many similar questions on this site. You might do a little reading and see if yours is already addressed. If not, the usual followups involve dimmer type, wiring configuration, etc. Please revise to add details.

Comment: Do you have any of the following on this circuit? Motion sensor, dimmer, timer, smart switch. Can you upload a picture showing the wiring in the ceiling?

Comment: Both lights flashing did you wire them in series or parallel?

Comment: Can you post photos of how you wired them?